# Can I run Discourse on a headless server with no GUI?

Tags: desktop

I have Ubuntu 20.04.3 on a Raspberry Pi 4B.
I am unable to install any GUI desktop apps.
The purpose of building this server was to run Discourse or similar service.
So far all applications that require a GUI display fail to run due to "No Display".

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

It is unusual for a Unix-like server to run a GUI. Ubuntu Server, for example, has no GUI. Services such as Discourse just communicate the data to be rendered by clients and are not rendered on the server.